# JHipster and Liquibase - Execution failed for task liquibaseClearChecksums

Tags: gradle, jhipster, liquibase

I have generated a JHipster application using these values:

```
{   
    "generator-jhipster": 
    {
        "jhipsterVersion": "4.13.0",
        "baseName": "app",
        "packageName": "my.app",
        "packageFolder": "my/app",
        "serverPort": "8080",
        "authenticationType": "session",
        "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
        "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
        "websocket": "no",
        "databaseType": "sql",
        "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
        "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
        "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
        "buildTool": "gradle",
        "enableSocialSignIn": false,
        "rememberMeKey": "",
        "clientFramework": "angularX",
        "useSass": true,
        "applicationType": "monolith",
        "testFrameworks": [
          "gatling",
          "cucumber",
          "protractor"
         ],
        "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
        "enableTranslation": false  
    }  
}
```

When I try to run this task `./gradlew liquibaseClearChecksums` I got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script '/home/james/appz/1-current-projects/jhipster/angelstore/gradle/liquibase.gradle' line: 36

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':liquibaseClearChecksums'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':liquibase'.
   > Could not find org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:.
     Required by:
         project :
```

I have added this line on build.gradle file:

`compile group: 'org.liquibase.ext', name: 'liquibase-hibernate5', version: '3.6'`

but the error keeps appearing when I run `./gradlew liquibaseClearChecksums`

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to JHipster 4.14.0 (run `jhipster upgrade`) or patch your gradle files as in [this commit](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6914/commits/3db181c316a0a4d927099d033cb38c3beb8f4c98)

Comment: The upgrade made me lost my changes in the current project, so I went back to my last commit.  It worked after applying the patch on the commit you said.  Thank you.

Comment: This is strange because the [upgrade generator](http://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/) uses all the power of git mergie with adequate strategies to keep your custom changes. Could you share a git repo or the trace of the execution of `jhipster upgrade`command? Is it the first time that you run it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the git repo.  The trace is too big for this comment.  I noticed the issue in my front end because I've used the option overwrite all in the last time and it overlaped part of my front end (home and footer components for example).  Next time I upgrade I will be alert all those questions of conflict.  BTW,  this error was happening after the upgrade when run ./gradlew: 'Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory'